# Mobile Vertically Scrolling not working *Sprite Spin*

Tags: android, jquery, html, ios, css

**Goal**

The goal would be to use sprite spin or something similar to be able to create a plug and play 360 product viewer.

**Problem**

I've gotten the 360 view to work perfect however on mobile only it doesn't allow you to vertically scroll down past the image. In the final project the product is full width and there for you can't avoid it.

**Current Progress**

Ive tired an number of things from

```
$("#mySpriteSpin").spritespin({
  //Function Settings
}).on("touchstart touchmove touchend scroll", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

to manually adding the scroll on touch (this disables it all together).

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/gxzfgugk/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try adding `pointer-events: none;` to a div wrapping `#mySpriteSpin`?

```
<div style="pointer-events: none;">      
    <div id="mySpriteSpin"></div>
</div>
```

Do it only if the user is using a mobile device. This solution worked for me.

Comment: I can't remember its been a while now since I completed that project, Thank you for your answer though and I'm sure it will come in help for me in the future!